# Display JSON array grouped by tr value

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape and get the data in specific group but the result is different than I expected. This is my tbody data:

```
<table class="travel-history-table">
<tbody>
  <tr class="travel-history-table__scan-event-date-row">
    <td class="travel-history-table__date">Friday, February 11, 2022</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="travel-history-table__scan-event-details-row">
    <td class="travel-history-table__time-stamp">11:18 AM</td>
    <td class="travel-history-table__location">DUBAI UAE AE</td>
    <td class="travel-history-table__event-status">Delivered</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="travel-history-table__scan-event-details-row">
    <td class="travel-history-table__time-stamp">8:15 AM</td>
    <td class="travel-history-table__location">DUBAI CITY AE</td>
    <td class="travel-history-table__event-status">On vehicle for delivery</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="travel-history-table__scan-event-date-row">
    <td class="travel-history-table__date">Thursday, February 10, 2022</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="travel-history-table__scan-event-details-row">
    <td class="travel-history-table__time-stamp">4:40 AM</td>
    <td class="travel-history-table__location">MEMPHIS, TN</td>
    <td class="travel-history-table__event-status">In transit</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="travel-history-table__scan-event-details-row">
    <td class="travel-history-table__time-stamp">4:40 AM</td>
    <td class="travel-history-table__location">MEMPHIS, TN</td>
    <td class="travel-history-table__event-status">Departed hub</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="travel-history-table__scan-event-date-row">
    <td class="travel-history-table__date">Wednesday, February 9, 2022</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="travel-history-table__scan-event-details-row">
    <td class="travel-history-table__time-stamp">8:21 AM</td>
    <td class="travel-history-table__location">MEMPHIS, TN</td>
    <td class="travel-history-table__event-status">In transit</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="travel-history-table__scan-event-details-row">
    <td class="travel-history-table__time-stamp">4:43 AM</td>
    <td class="travel-history-table__location">MEMPHIS, TN</td>
    <td class="travel-history-table__event-status">In transit</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="travel-history-table__scan-event-details-row">
    <td class="travel-history-table__time-stamp">3:35 AM</td>
    <td class="travel-history-table__location">NEWARK, NJ</td>
    <td class="travel-history-table__event-status">In transit</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="travel-history-table__scan-event-details-row">
    <td class="travel-history-table__time-stamp">2:03 AM</td>
    <td class="travel-history-table__location">MEMPHIS, TN</td>
    <td class="travel-history-table__event-status">Arrived at hub</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So far my scrape result looks like this:

```
[
  {
    date: 'Friday, February 11, 2022',
    time: {
      '0': '11:18 AM',
      '1': '8:15 AM',
      '2': '4:40 AM',
      '3': '4:40 AM',
      '4': '8:21 AM',
      '5': '4:43 AM',
      '6': '3:35 AM',
      '7': '2:03 AM',
    },
    location: {
      '0': 'DUBAI UAE AE',
      '1': 'DUBAI CITY AE',
      '2': 'DUBAI CITY AE',
      '3': 'DUBAI AE',
      '4': 'DUBAI AE',
      '5': 'DUBAI AE',
      '6': 'DUBAI AE',
      '7': 'DUBAI CITY AE',
    },
    status: {
      '0': 'Delivered',
      '1': 'On vehicle for delivery',
      '2': 'At local facility',
      '3': 'In transit',
      '4': 'In transit',
      '5': 'In transit',
      '6': 'In transit',
      '7': 'At destination sort facility',
    }
  }
]
```

But I want to display the result grouped by by datetime like this:

```
[
  {
    date: 'Friday, February 11, 2022',
    time: {
      '0': '11:18 AM',
      '1': '8:15 AM',
    },
    location: {
      '0': 'DUBAI UAE AE',
      '1': 'DUBAI CITY AE',
    },
    status: {
      '0': 'Delivered',
      '1': 'On vehicle for delivery',
    }
  },
  {
    date: 'Thursday, February 10, 2022',
    time: {
      '0': '4:40 AM',
      '1': '4:40 AM',
    },
    location: {
      '0': 'DUBAI CITY AE',
      '1': 'DUBAI AE',
    },
    status: {
      '0': 'At local facility',
      '1': 'In transit',
    }
  }
  
  omitted ...
]
```

This is how I did so far:

```
const resultCheckpoints = await page.$$('.travel-history-table');       
if (resultCheckpoints.length > 0){
    const result = await page.$$eval('.travel-history-table', (msgs) => msgs.map((msg) => {
        return {
            date: msg.querySelector('.travel-history-table__date').innerText,
            time: Object.assign({}, Array.from(msg.querySelectorAll('.travel-history-table__time-stamp'), (el) => el.textContent.trim())),
            location: Object.assign({}, Array.from(msg.querySelectorAll('.travel-history-table__location'), (el) => el.textContent.trim())),
            status: Object.assign({}, Array.from(msg.querySelectorAll('.travel-history-table__event-status'), (el) => el.textContent.trim()))
        }})
    );

    console.log(result);
}
```

How can I display as above?

Answer (score 0):

They haven't made it easy for you with that page structure, unfortunately.  It will take a little work.  I think I would process each TR separately - the problem is that you need to separate the groups of rows manually.  So, something like...

```
msgs.map(msg => {
    const items = [];
    let currentItem;
    
    msg.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach(row => {
        if(row.querySelectorAll(".travel-history-table__date").length) {
            items.push(currentItem = {});
        }
        // parse this row and add its data to currentItem as appropriate.
    });
    
    return items;
})
```